# Join / subquery for SQL

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with the following question:

Query all customers who spent 50% of less than the average amount spent on all invoices. For each customer, display their name and the amount spent to 6 decimals. Order the result by the amount spent from high to low.

[image: customer]

[image: invoice]

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the customers with their amount spent below the invoice average, try this:

```
SELECT customer_name, CAST(SUM(total_price) AS DECIMAL(20,6) AS amount
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN invoice i 
ON c.id = i.customer_id 
WHERE amount < (SELECT AVG(total_price) FROM i)
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use a `having` clause after aggregation:

```
SELECT c.id, c.customer_name, SUM(total_price) AS amount
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     invoice i 
     ON c.id = i.customer_id 
GROUP BY c.id, c.customer_name
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(total_price), 0) < (SELECT AVG(total_price) FROM i) ;
```

Note:  This includes customers with no invoices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function to calculate customer wise total and total average for invoice table then join that to customer table like below:

```
  select customer_name,round(max(customer_total),6) as amount_spent
    from customer c
    inner join (
                    select  customer_id,sum(total_price)over(partition by customer_id) Customer_Total, avg(total_price)over() Total_average from invoice) i
        on c.id=i.customer_id            
    where customer_total<=total_average?2
    group by customer_name
    order by customer_total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL I would do it likewise:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, CAST(SUM(total_price) AS DECIMAL (20,6)) AS amount
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN invoice i 
ON c.id = i.customer_id 
GROUP BY c.customer_name
HAVING SUM(total_price), 0 < 0.5*(SELECT AVG(total_price) FROM invoice)
ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working query for MySql -

```
 SELECT customer.customer_name,CAST(invoice.total_price AS DECIMAL(10,6)) 
      Amount 
    FROM customer 
      INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice.customer_id=customer.id 
    WHERE invoice.total_price<= (SELECT (0.25*AVG(invoice.total_price)) 
    FROM invoice ) 
    GROUP BY customer.id,customer.customer_name,invoice.total_price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.customer_name, CAST((total_price) as decimal(10, 6))
FROM
    customer as a
    JOIN invoice as b ON a.id = b.customer_id
WHERE
    total_price <= (SELECT 0.25 * AVG(total_price) FROM invoice)
GROUP BY
    a.customer_name,total_price
ORDER BY
    total_price DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

On MYSQL it can be done with this query:

```
select b.customer_name,cast(a.total_price as decimal(10,6))amount from customer b, invoice a where a.customer_id=b.id and a.total_price<=(select (0.25*avg(a.total_price)) FROM invoice a) order by amount desc ;
```

Answer (score -1):

On MSSQL I have used this solution and it verifies the test:

```
SELECT a.customer_name, CAST((total_price) as decimal(20,6)) --6 decimals place
FROM customer as a
JOIN invoice as b ON a.id = b.customer_id
GROUP BY a.customer_name
HAVING total_price <= (SELECT AVG(total_price)*50/100 FROM invoice)
ORDER BY total_price DESC;
```